# Elasticsearch score results based partly on Popularity

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, lucene

I'm using Elasticsearch for this project but a Solr solution might be appropriate too. In the query I'd like to include a portion of a `should` clause that will return results even if none of the other terms can. This will be used for document popularity. I'll periodically calculate reading popularity and add a float field to each doc with a numeric value.

The idea is to return docs based on terms but when that fails, return popular docs ranked by popularity. These should be ordered by term match scores or magnitude of popularity score.

I realize that I could quantize the popularity and treat it like a tag "hottest", "hotter", "hot"... but would like to use numeric field since the ranking is well defined.

Here is the current form of my data (from fetch by id):

```
GET /index/docs/ipad
```

returns a sample object

```
{
   "_index": "index",
   "_type": "docs",
   "_id": "doc1",
   "_version": 1,
   "found": true,
   "_source": {
      "category": ["tablets", "electronics"],
      "text": ["buy", "an",  "ipad"],
      "popularity": 0.95347457,
      "id": "doc1"
   }
}
```

Current query format

```
POST /index/docs/_search
{
   "size": 10,
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "should": [
            {"terms": {"text": ["ipad"]}}
         ],
         "must": [
            {"terms": {"category": ["electronics"]}}
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

This may seem an odd query format but these are structured objects, not free form text.

Can I add popularity to this query so that it returns items ranked by popularity magnitude along with those returned by the `should` terms? I'd boost the actual terms above the popularity so they'd be favored.

**Note** I do not want to boost by popularity, I want to return popular if the rest of the query returns nothing.

Comment: would  sort by score followed by popularity  not work  ?

Comment: Looking for something that will return hits even if nothing else does. So imagine the query above hitting nothing--this is the case I want popularity to fallback to, so every query returns something, if only the most popular docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach I can think of is wrapping [match_all filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-all-filter.html) in  [constant score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html) 
and using sort on score followed by popularity

example:

```
    {
   "size": 10,
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "should": [
            {
               "terms": {
                  "text": [
                     "ipad"
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "constant_score": {
                  "filter": {
                     "match_all": {}
                  },
                  "boost": 0
               }
            }
         ],
         "must": [
            {
               "terms": {
                  "category": [
                     "electronics"
                  ]
               }
            }
         ],
         "minimum_should_match": 1
      }
   },
   "sort": [
      {
         "_score": {
            "order": "desc"
         }
      },
      {
         "popularity": {
            "unmapped_type": "double"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Looks promising with one question. The constant score returns the boost all the time so that will be 0. So nothing to sort by when no hits are from the query part. Then in the sort we use any hits by score, but if it's the `match_all` hit the `_score` will be 0 and the `popularity` will take over. However I don't get what would happen if the query part did return results. I guess the `popularity` value should always be mapped to a number smaller than a hit scores? Not sure how to do that. Scores will be 0..1 right?

Comment: since we sort  first by *score* then by *popularity*  .Documents which are  "valid hits"  would always have a score greater that 0 i.e. documents which are there as a result of only *match_all* would  always show lower down. However  there is one issue though if you ask for 10 results and you get only 2 valid hits the rest 8 would be documents ordered by popularity

Comment: Got it, thanks and that actually that sounds about right. I forgot to say that I still want the `must` filters to apply so all hits obey the `category` filter above. I guess that means the constant score/match_all must be subject to the `must`? Also I assume there may be duplicate hits?

Comment: what if there are no documents matching the category do you not want results to be returned based on popularity ?

Comment: No, the category or anything in `must` may overconstrain the query but that's ok. It's for an app and the need is to have only items matching the `must` where `should` matches are favored and popular are backfill but everything is subject to `must`.  Does that mean I take the inner `must` and move it to the outer `bool`. Sorry just getting started with ES JSON.

Comment: yeah that would work the query i have updated the query in the answer

Comment: I'm beginning to see, thanks, marked as the answer. BTW the `match_all`, which triggers the sort of everything, is that going to give me a long query time?

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into the [function score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) and a decay function for this.

Here's a gentle intro: https://www.found.no/foundation/function-scoring/

Comment: Thanks I've read this before but my understanding is that this affects the score and in my case there will be no score to affect without popularity. I don't want to re-score based on popularity I want popularity to kick in if nothing else hits.